# Snowflake: Find changes and type of changes in table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hello I'm trying to identify deltas(changes) and the type of deltas(changes)
Within a table
If it's a change
Is there a recommended approach to get what field changed in Snowflake

I believe the below query reflects Adds and I can flip this to get deletes

Suggestions please
Thanks

```
      SELECT 'Customer' as Tablename,
      'Add' as DeltaType,
      d1.File_Date AS month,
      count(d1.Cust_Number) AS NumRecords
      FROM CUSTOMER d1
      Where File_Date = '20230822'
      and d1.Cust_Number Not in (
                            SELECT Cust_Number
                            FROM CUSTOMER d1
                            Where File_Date <= '20230724'
                           )
      Group by d1.File_Date
```

Comment: You should probably provide more information about how data is being loaded into your table, because that query looks like you have 2 full versions of data in a single table with different file_date?  If you instead had a table and applied the changes directly so there was only 1 version of the data, you could use a stream to capture the changes.

Comment: Our platform team recently informed us that this data is loaded monthly and it's a deltas. File_Date is the date the vendor supplied the data. The issue is that for the Aug2023 File delivery we saw of 30 million deltas between the previous month.  I'd like to get an understanding of what is actually changing in the records

Comment: If your table only contains the deltas for each month then the comparison is going to be complex as you'd need to compare the current delta against every other delta and for each customer try and find the most recent change - it would be much simpler if you has a table with just the current version of each customer (i.e. the cumulative position). However, whatever you are comparing against, I would start by finding records in the latest delta that don;t already exist (i.e. new customer) as you can exclude them from any comparison.

Comment: Then, if the record has lots of columns, create a hash of the columns and compare hashes - so you're not trying to compare every column  individually. Where the hashes are different you know there is a change so you can dig into those specific changed records to understand the detail

Comment: You may want to configure a SCD approach as described in https://medium.com/snowflake/slowly-changing-dimensions-with-dynamic-tables-d0d76582ff31